# How to generate Universally Unique IDentifier, UUID from LoadRunner independent of the OS

Tags: c, performance-testing, uuid, guid, loadrunner

I have experienced the need of generating UUID in LoadRunner several times while scripting but there is no in-build function to do so. I am using both linux and windows load generators.

Thanks to Scott Moore for writing the below code which uses windows in-build CoCreateGuid function (dependent on ole32.dll) to generate required UUID. However that code is completely dependent on windows platform and doesn't work in Linux platform.

How can we generate UUID from Loadrunner independent of OS?

```
    #include "lrun.h"
    #include "web_api.h"
    #include "lrw_custom_body.h"
    #include "stdlib.h"
    #include "stdio.h"
    #include "string.h"
    int lr_guid_gen()
    {
        typedef struct _GUID
        {
            unsigned long Data1;
            unsigned short Data2;
            unsigned short Data3;
            unsigned char Data4[8];
        } GUID;

        GUID m_guid;
        char buf[50];

        lr_load_dll ("ole32.dll");

        CoCreateGuid(&m_guid);

        sprintf (buf, "%08lx-%04x-%04x-%02x%02x-%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x",
        m_guid.Data1, m_guid.Data2, m_guid.Data3,
        m_guid.Data4[0], m_guid.Data4[1], m_guid.Data4[2], m_guid.Data4[3],
        m_guid.Data4[4], m_guid.Data4[5], m_guid.Data4[6], m_guid.Data4[7]);

        lr_save_string(buf, "PAR_GUID");

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have to use Web HTTP protocol because in TruWeb protocol it would be much easier.

Comment: Yes, it's for web HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following trick which doesn't require any code. 
Define a hex parameter as follows:
[image]

Then use it with this code:
`lr_eval_string("{MyHex}{MyHex}-{MyHex}-{MyHex}-{MyHex}-{MyHex}{MyHex}{MyHex}")`

Comment: There is also an option to use JavaScript. If you want me to post that as well please comment below.

Comment: I have tried that trick with the loadrunner parameters, but that didn't work with the requests.

Comment: It should have worked. If you post the code that didn't work I can check why.

Comment: This is amazing @Buzzy. No coding and served the purpose. Thanks

Comment: @Buzzy please post JavaScript option, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with the below mentioned solution

```
int lr_guid_gen()
{
    char GUID[40];
    int t = 0;
    char *szTemp = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    char *szHex = "0123456789abcdef-";
    int nLen = strlen (szTemp);


    for (t=0; t<nLen+1; t++)
    {
        int r = rand () % 16;
        char c = ' ';   

        switch (szTemp[t])
        {
            case 'x' : { c = szHex [r]; } break;
            case 'y' : { c = szHex [r & 0x03 | 0x08]; } break;
            case '-' : { c = '-'; } break;
            case '4' : { c = '4'; } break;
        }

        GUID[t] = ( t < nLen ) ? c : 0x00;
    }

    lr_save_string(GUID,"PAR_GUID");

    return 0;
}
```